# Spring Data JPA and QueryDSL - No property find found for type

Tags: jpa, predicate, querydsl

I'm using Spring JPA 1.7 and QueryDSL 3.5.1. I am getting 'No property find found' error.
Here are my classes.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Device")
public class Device implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotEmpty
    @Id
    @Column(name="deviceId")
    private String deviceId="";

    @Column(name="accountId")
    private String accountId="";

    @Column(name="groupId")
    private String groupId="";

    @Column(name="equipmentType")
    private String equipmentType="";

    @Column(name="deviceCode")
    private String deviceCode="";

    @Column(name="deviceType")
    private String deviceType="";

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="simId")
    private String simId="";

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="imeiNumber")
    private String imeiNumber="";

    @Column(name="simPhoneNumber")
    private String simPhoneNumber="";

    @Column(name="driverId")
    private String driverId="";

    @Column(name="pushpinId")
    private String pushpinId=""; //who registered device? JMA/MDM/JAMS

    @Column(name="isActive", columnDefinition="INT(1)")
    private boolean isActive = false;

    @Column(name="displayName")
    private String displayName="";


    @Column(name="description")
    private String description="";

    @Column(name="notes")
    private String notes="";

    @Column
    @JsonSerialize(using=DateSerializer.class)
    private long creationTime;

    @Column
    @JsonSerialize(using=DateSerializer.class)
    private long lastUpdateTime;

    //Getters and setters

}


public interface DeviceRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Device, String>, DeviceRepositoryCustom {

    public Page<Device> findAll(com.mysema.query.types.Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);

}

public interface DeviceRepositoryCustom {

    public List<Device> selectByEquipmentTypeAndAnyColumnLike(String equipmentType, String creationTime, String searchField, String searchText, boolean hasPushId);

}


public class MdmPredicates {

    public static com.mysema.query.types.Predicate anyFieldLike(String field, String text) {
        QDevice device = QDevice.device;

        //Do something later

        return device.deviceId.contains(text);
    }
}

Here is the error log:

aused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property find found for type entities.Device
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:271)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:245)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:188)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:257)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:290)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:158)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:44)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168)
```

I know that the error happens when I don't use real column name instead of property name. But the property names in the class are all same with column names.

Would you please tell me what I am I missing? 
Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like this is not caused by Querydsl but another Spring Data querying option.

Comment: Have you, by any chance, fixed that problem? If so, do you remember how?